# Excel Automation - Filter COM events using FindConnectionPoint

Tags: c++, excel, windows, automation, com

I use C++ COM to listen to events IID_ApplicationEvents of an existing Excel application. My code is placed in a separate EXE file.
The Connection point is initialized with the following code:

```
    IConnectionPointContainer* pCPC = NULL;
    hr = pEventSource->QueryInterface(IID_IConnectionPointContainer,
        (void**)&pCPC);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)){
        hr = pCPC->FindConnectionPoint(IID_ApplicationEvents, &m_pConnectionPoint);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)){
            hr = m_pConnectionPoint->Advise(this, &m_dwConnection);
            if (FAILED(hr))         
                LOG_ERROR(L"m_pConnectionPoint->Advise - FAIL");
        }
        else
            LOG_ERROR(L"FindConnectionPoint - IID_ApplicationEvents: FAIL");

        pCPC->Release();
    }
    else
        LOG_ERROR(L"IID_IConnectionPointContainer: FAIL");
    return hr;
```

I am receiving the Excel events via the Invoke function:

```
STDMETHODIMP Invoke(DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid,
    WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pDispParams,
    VARIANT* pVarResult, EXCEPINFO* pExcepInfo,
    UINT* puArgErr)
```

My question is following: In order to improve the performance of my app and not slow down the running Excel, I am interested only in OnBeforeSave and OnClose events. Is there a way to filter out other Excel events in my process (I dont want my Invoke function to be called at all)?

Comment: No, there is no way. When you attach to a connection point, you subscribe to all events emitted by that connection point. You can ignore those you don't care about, but you can't avoid getting called for them.

Comment: What is the value of IID_ApplicationEvents here?

Answer (score 1):

As Igor mentioned in a comment above, you cannot simply filter events. However, you can build something yourself to do this.

Here's one way:

- Create a COM Add-in that will be loaded in the Excel process. (See [`IDTExtensibility2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2.aspx)).
- When [`OnConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2.onconnection.aspx) is called:

  - Create an instance of your own homegrown event filter class (implement [`IDispatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608(v=vs.85).aspx) to handle events and [`IConnectionPointContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683857(v=vs.85).aspx) to raise events).
  - Make that event filter object "public" by assigning its [`IUnknown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680509(v=vs.85).aspx) pointer to the [`Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.addin.object) property of the [`AddIn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/addin-object-excel) object supplied as the [`AddInIst`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2.onconnection.aspx) parameter to [`OnConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/extensibility.idtextensibility2.onconnection.aspx).
- When your event filter object receives an event, filter it according to your rules. If the event isn't filtered out, raise it from the filter object.
- In your external process, find your COM Add-In in the [`AddIns2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/addins2-object-excel) collection and read its `Object` property. You can then treat that as your event source instead of the `Application` object.